# How to convert an epoch time in millisecond into an ISO like string according to local time?

Tags: json, datetime, jq, iso8601, milliseconds

```
$ TZ=America/New_York jq -r '((./1000 | floor | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "." + (.%1000 | tostring | ("0" * (3 - length)) + .)))' <<< 1642812926681 # Time is in the number of epoch millisecond.
2022-01-21 19:55:26.926
```

I can come up with some like the above for the conversion. Is this the most appropriate way to perform such a conversion? How to define a function for such a conversion so that I don't have to always type such a long jq command?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no placeholder for milliseconds. But you could replace `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` with `%F %T` which makes it at least a little bit shorter, though

Comment: How to define a function with your simplification?

Comment: From the jq FAQ: strflocaltime in jq version 1.6 and earlier has silent bugs (see e.g. https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/2202). We suggest you check the results, e.g. using gojq, the Go implementation of jq, or use gojq instead for transformations involving "local time". [https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ]

Comment: The program you have doesn't actually work (due to bad placement of parens). `...681` should produce something that ends in `.681`

Comment: @peak, The ticket to which you link says that only `%Z` is broken. (And I wouldn't be surprised if `%z` was broken too.) [My testing](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/79a95fe4739ced1abddfe6ee0bdcd1fb) seems to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

If your system/environment implements the placeholder `%N` for nanoseconds, you could use `%3N` to get the padded milliseconds:

```sh
TZ=America/New_York jq -r '
  
  def mydate:
    ./1000 | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N");
  
  mydate

' <<< 1642812926681
```

```
2022-01-21 19:55:26.681
```

No Demo ([jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/) does not support the `%N` placeholder)

---

If it doesn't, you could still do some tweaks to shorten it:

- omit calculating the `floor` for the whole seconds as `strflocaltime` will take care of it
- replace `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` with `%F %T`
- use string interpolation `"\(…)"` for easier string conversion

```sh
TZ=America/New_York jq -r '
  
  def mydate:
    (./1000 | strflocaltime("%F %T.")) + "00\(.%1000)"[-3:];
  
  mydate

' <<< 1642812926681
```

```
2022-01-21 19:55:26.681
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JqemgHwZuV)

Comment: There is a bug. For the second approach, when the input is `1642812926100`, the output is `2022-01-21 19:55:26.1`. The correct output should be `2022-01-21 19:55:26.100`. How to fix this bug?

Comment: It is still wrong. 1642812926001 and 1642812926100 both give `2022-01-21 19:55:26.100`. The result should be different.

Comment: @user1424739 Where was my mind... Really fixed it now.